# How to change calendar settings to month view?

Tags: settings

My calendar is stuck on viewing the agenda when I open it.  I would like to view the month page when I open it. How can I configure it to work like this?

Comment: What is "your calendar"? There are thousands of calendar apps around. Even the pre-installed calendar differs between manufacturers. Could you please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46933/edit) your question and add a few more details: which device you are using, what Android version, what calendar app? Without those details, we are unable to help you.